# How do you update an MTurk worker qualification score with boto3?

Tags: aws-sdk, boto3, mechanicalturk

The older MTurk API (and `boto2`) had an [`UpdateQualificationScore`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMechanicalTurkRequester/Concepts_QualificationsArticle.html#updating-and-retrieving-qualification-scores) method that would allow users to update the score of a specific worker, but this seems to have disappeared in the latest version(s) based on `boto3`.

The latest MTurk API has a `GetQualificationScore` method (which actually returns a full worker qualification record, not just the score), but no corresponding `UpdateQualificationScore` method.  What is the mechanism to update a score for an existing worker?

Answer (score 1):

As best as I can tell, the proper way to do this with the `boto3` is to use the `AssociateQualificationWithWorker` endpoint:

```py
session = boto3.Session(profile_name='mturk')
client = session.client('mturk')
response = client.associate_qualification_with_worker(
    QualificationTypeId=qualification_type_id,
    WorkerId=worker_id,
    IntegerValue=score,
    SendNotification=False,
)
```

This *seems* to work, especially when taken alongside `GetQualificationScore` returning the "full" qualification record instead of just the score.

Answer (score 0):

ex-nerd's answer is correct. Building off the Python sample available at http://requester.mturk.com/developer, the following works to assign a QualificationType then change the score for that Worker:

```
import boto3

region_name = 'us-east-1'
aws_access_key_id = 'YOUR_ACCESS_ID'
aws_secret_access_key = 'YOUR_SECRET_KEY'

endpoint_url = 'https://mturk-requester-sandbox.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'

# Uncomment this line to use in production
# endpoint_url = 'https://mturk-requester.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'

client = boto3.client(
    'mturk',
    endpoint_url=endpoint_url,
    region_name=region_name,
    aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id,
    aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key,
)

# This will assign the QualificationType
client.associate_qualification_with_worker(QualificationTypeId = '3KIOU9ULHKIIS5OPUVORW7OE1070V0', WorkerId = 'A39ECJ12CY7TE9', IntegerValue = 100)

# This will set the QualificationScore from 100 to 90
client.associate_qualification_with_worker(QualificationTypeId = '3KIOU9ULHKIIS5OPUVORW7OE1070V0', WorkerId = 'A39ECJ12CY7TE9', IntegerValue = 90)
```

Comment: I should add that, in practice, there's about a 30-60 second propagation delay in seeing the WorkerScore update on www.mturk.com. Just a heads-up so that you're not thrown by this when trying to figure out if your call to associate_qualification_with_worker worked or not.